# CakePHP Custom Query

Tags: cakephp

Anybody knows how to execute this using the famous Cakephp ORM-based 'find' query function?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id 
                                          FROM classification 
                                          WHERE class_name = '".$classname."')";
```

What I want to do is to get the id of the user ( from `users` table ) whenever a class_name is submitted.

As you can see, the user_id is the foreign key of the `classifications` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have User and Classification models with Classification having hasMany relationship to User, you can go with

```
$result = $this->Classification->find('first', array('conditions' => array(
    'Classification.class_name' => $classname
)));

foreach ($result['Classification']['User'] as $user)
    echo 'User id: ' . $user['id'] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do have a question.. Can we execute ConnectionManager :: getDataSource('second_db') inside the User model? Because I'm using external connection to another non-cake app. Or do I need to create another fresh model that relates to that application but resides inside CakePHP? Or, am I silly enough to ask this? :)

Comment: better to use a model with the specific datasource specified.